# How do I compare two dates which are stored in string with help of string operator?

Tags: c#, date, datetime, compare

I want to check today with expiry day for login purpose for users
Here is my code

```
string today = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
command = new SqlCommand("select * from CompanyRegistered where Comp_Id=" + CompanyRegId, connection);

SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();
DateTime TheDate = dr.GetDateTime(5);


string strDate = TheDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

//string up=    Convert.ToDateTime(MyReader["AccountExpiry"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
int result = today.CompareTo(strDate);
if (result > 0)
{
}
```

Comment: for date comparison, you can use "=", "<", or ">"

Comment: Why on earth would you convert datetime to string for a comparison?

Comment: why not use DateTime instead of String?

Comment: use DateTime > < build in comparators - not ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime TheDate = dr.GetDateTime(5);
```

means your value in stored within the DB as a `DateTime`.

Please, do not convert it to string. Compare `DateTime` values instead:

```
DateTime theDate = dr.GetDateTime(5);
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
if (today > theDate)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Don't**. Only use `string`s for things that need to be text, like when you want to display a date.

You already have the values you want as proper `DateTime`s so you can just compare them:

```
using(SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader()) 
{
  if(dr.Read() && !dr.IsDbNull(5)) 
  {
    DateTime userExpiryDate = dr.GetDateTime(5);  
    if (userExpiryDate > DateTime.Today)
    {
      // Do something
    }
  }
}
```

Side note: add some error handling - you may not get any records, or a `null` value. Also, check out `using` - many of the SQL classes such as `SqlConnection` `SqlDataReader` are `IDisposable` and thus need to be `Dispose()`d after use.